# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am creating  Sample Spring MVC application. In my Controller class I have define like this:

```
Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        myModel.put("now", now);
        myModel.put("products", this.productManager.getProducts());

        return new ModelAndView("hello", "model", myModel);
```

When I put following part in my JSP file i got `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` exception

```
<c:forEach items="${model.products}" var="prod">
        <c:out value="${prod.description}"/> <i>$<c:out value="${prod.price}"/></i><br><br>
    </c:forEach>
```

Here is my full exception :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'description'.
```

But in  my domain class `private Sting description` property has public getter and setter. That `Product` class is public one.

Product class:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private String description;
    private Double price;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

**PS:**

If I used like this it's working

```
<c:forEach items="${model.products}" var="prod"  varStatus="status">        
        <c:out value="${model.products[status.count -1].description}"/> <i>$<c:out value="${model.products[status.count -1].price}"/></i><br><br>
    </c:forEach>
```

But recommended solution not working :(

Comment: Seems fine to me. I'd double check that the value you expect to be in `prod` is in `prod` by printing its value *before* the `<c:out>` line.

Comment: I have change my code like this:

`<c:forEach items="${model.products}" var="prod">
  <c:out value="${prod}"/>       
    </c:forEach>`


Now Output is:

`[Description: Lamp;Price: 5.75 Description: Table;Price: 75.25 Description: Chair;Price: 22.79]`

Comment: What happens if you try and access the first item directly with EL before the `<c:forEach>`? e.g. `<c:out value="${model.products[0].description}"/>`

Comment: `<c:out value="${model.products[0].description}"/>`  it show value as ` Lamp`

Comment: What about using `<c:set var="prod1" value="${prod}"/>` before the `<c:out>` and then using `prod1` instead of `prod` in your `<c:out>`?

Comment: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/hello.jsp(10,2) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions`

line 10 is :`<c:set var="prod1" value="${prod}"/>`

Comment: Can you show your taglib import from your JSP? It sounds like you might be referring to the wrong taglib, one that doesn't support expressions totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe check your taglib import:

OLD

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

NEW

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Is your `Product` class and its getters accessible? By this I broadly mean are they `public`?

See http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58420-Problem-with-javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException.

Comment: Yes Product class public one and it has getter and setter also.

Comment: I have change the tag lib import to `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`  Now working fine.

Answer (score 5):

This happen when you are passing a String to an EL operation c:forEach instead of an iterable element, in the following example I miss the '$' so it's passing the exact String without variable resolution.

```
<c:forEach var="o" items="{operations}">
```

The next is right because operation is a String[] in my code

```
<c:forEach var="o" items="${operations}">
```

Comment: These are 2 hours lost due to a silly reason... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<c:forEach items="${model['products']}" var="oneProduct">
    <c:out value="${oneProduct.description}"/> <i>$<c:out value="${oneProduct.price}"/>                            
    </i><br><br>
</c:forEach>
```

And check the capitalization of you gettters and setters, should be `getDescription()`

Comment: 'this.productManager.getProducts()' return Product list, not one object

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/hello.jsp(11,0) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: @Chandana, capitalization of your getter ?

Comment: No I have generate getter and setter again, but same issue. :(