# MVC using java - returns NULL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, javabeans

I am trying MVC using jsp servlets. But couldnt return the values from the database through bean.

Below is my code:

**JSP page** :

```
        <c:forEach var="pro" items="list">
         <tr>        
            <td><c:out value="${pro.reqno}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pro.leave_Type}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pro.no_of_days}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pro.status}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pro.balanceUnits}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${pro.totalUnits}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
       </c:forEach>
```

**Servlet** :

```
            SummaryDetail summary=new SummaryDetail();
            ArrayList temp=new ArrayList();
            temp=summary.getSummary();
            request.setAttribute("list", temp);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP page");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

**DAO class:**

```
    public ArrayList<LeaveSummary> getSummary(){
    ArrayList<LeaveSummary> rowArray = new ArrayList<LeaveSummary>();
     try{
        LeaveSummary getValuesFromDb=new LeaveSummary();
        Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();    
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT REQNO,USERNAME,LEAVEUNITS,LEAVETYPE,STATUS,TOTALUNITS,BALANCEUNITS FROM leave_request");
        while(rs.next())
        {
          getValuesFromDb.setReqno(rs.getInt(1));
          getValuesFromDb.setUser_name(rs.getString(2));
          getValuesFromDb.setNo_of_days(rs.getInt(3));
          getValuesFromDb.setLeave_Type(rs.getString(4));
          getValuesFromDb.setStatus(rs.getString(5));
          getValuesFromDb.setTotalUnits(rs.getInt(6));
          getValuesFromDb.setBalanceUnits(rs.getInt(7));
          rowArray.add(getValuesFromDb);
        }
    }
   catch(Exception e)
           {}
    return rowArray;
    }
```

**Bean class:**

```
public class LeaveSummary {

public int getBalanceUnits() {
    return balanceUnits;
}

public void setBalanceUnits(int balanceUnits) {
    this.balanceUnits = balanceUnits;
}

public String getLeave_Type() {
    return leave_Type;
}

public void setLeave_Type(String leave_Type) {
    this.leave_Type = leave_Type;
}

public int getNo_of_days() {
    return no_of_days;
}

public void setNo_of_days(int no_of_days) {
    this.no_of_days = no_of_days;
}

public int getReqno() {
    return reqno;
}

public void setReqno(int reqno) {
    this.reqno = reqno;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public int getTotalUnits() {
    return totalUnits;
}

public void setTotalUnits(int totalUnits) {
    this.totalUnits = totalUnits;
}

public String getUser_name() {
    return user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}
private int reqno;
private String leave_Type;
private int no_of_days; // represents no of days of leave that is LeaveUnits field in DB
private String user_name;
private int balanceUnits;
private String status;
private int totalUnits;



}
```

It does print any values in my JSP. Please explain me the mistake .Thanks in advance !!

Comment: where are you using `list` in your JSP?

Comment: Also having the LeaveSummary source code would be nice :]

Comment: Post your code how you are using your `list` in your jsp? Why there is nothing in your exception part. Try using `catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}`. Also try debug your code in case if you are using some IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: @michali,micha i have updated my code , please help me out

Comment: You don't need to first create an anmpty ArrayList in your servlet (which is immediately thrown away). Are you sure your servlet is invoked?

Comment: @Vinoth Cant understand . Do you want me to handle exceptions in JSP

Comment: @RogerLindsjö yes it is invoked, I tried printing the array list inside the servlet , it printed the object value

Comment: In DAO class print stack trace. `e.printStacktrace()` do not leave just empty braces `{}`

Comment: How does `SummaryDetail` class look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the mistake with the controller servlet .

```
 try {
            List temp = summary.getSummary();
            request.setAttribute("list", temp);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP/login-success.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not iterating list on jsp. Try below code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="pro">
            <tr>        
                        <td><c:out value="${pro.reqno}"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${pro.leave_Type}"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${pro.no_of_days}"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${pro.status}"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${pro.balanceUnits}"></c:out></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${pro.totalUnits}"></c:out></td>
                    </tr>                       
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Comment: Anyhow its not working . Getting this error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'reqno'

Comment: @sankrish did you tried to use <c:forEach items="${request.list}" var="pro"> ??

Comment: @sankrish : try this tag lib <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

Comment: @RahulSahu Thats was not the problem , i already imported the JSTL jars to my lib folder.

Comment: @sankrish now there is two tag lib. so which one you are using? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318004/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-the-class-java-lang-string-does-not-have-t

Comment: @RahulSahu Tried the new one also no change